# Normal form for Hopf bifurcation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, linear-algebra

I'm trying to obtain the normal form for the Hopf bifurcation using mathematica. I was looking at the following article:

downloads.hindawi.com/journals/sv/1995/581272.pdf

and I´ve tried to solve (25) in order to get to (26). Here's my code:

```
A = {{0, -β}, {β, 0}};(*//MatrixForm*)
h2 = {c20*y1^2 + c11*y1*y2 + c02*y2^2, d20*y1^2 + d11*y1*y2 + d02*y2^2 };
y = {y1, y2};
X2 = {a20*y1^2 + a11*y1*y2 + a02*y2^2, b20*y1^2 + b11*y1*y2 + b02*y2^2 };

Solve[D[h2, {y}].A.y - A.h2 - X2 == 0, {c20, c11, c02, d20, d11, d02}]
```

and my output:

```
{{d11 -> -((2 d20 y1)/y2) + (3 c20 y1^2)/(y1^2 + y2^2) - (
c02 (4 y1^2 + y2^2))/(y1^2 + y2^2) - (c11 (2 y1^3 - y1 y2^2))/(
y2 (y1^2 + y2^2)) - (-2 a20 y1^3 - 2 a11 y1^2 y2 + b20 y1^2 y2 - 
 2 a02 y1 y2^2 + b11 y1 y2^2 + b02 y2^3)/(
y2 (y1^2 + y2^2) β), d02 -> (d20 y1^2)/y2^2 + (c02 y1 (2 y1^2 - y2^2))/(
y2 (y1^2 + y2^2)) - (c20 (y1^3 - 2 y1 y2^2))/(
y2 (y1^2 + y2^2)) - (c11 (-y1^4 + y1^2 y2^2 - y2^4))/(
y2^2 (y1^2 + y2^2)) - (1/(
y2^2 (y1^2 + y2^2) β))(a20 y1^4 + a11 y1^3 y2 - 
  b20 y1^3 y2 + a02 y1^2 y2^2 - a20 y1^2 y2^2 - b11 y1^2 y2^2 - 
  a11 y1 y2^3 - b02 y1 y2^3 - a02 y2^4)}}
```

Clearly it is not doing what I want. Besides, can you suggest other ways to solve this problem (if they are simpler)?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, could you include your code as text, not as an image?  That makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: Just done it. Hope it's readable. I'm new to stackexchange so if it is helpful to further edit my question to make it more understandable please tell me so.

Comment: Then, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!